# Using a proxy per console application

Tags: c#, proxy, console-application

I have a VM that runs a few web crawling console applications.  I'm wondering how do you use a different proxy per console application.  Most of the proxy C# stuff I find changes the registry, however this changes all console apps not just one.

Anybody have an example of how to use a specific proxy for a specific console app without effective all other console apps?

Looking for a source code solution

Comment: Are you looking for a way to change the source code for one of the console applications or are you looking for an external way to control the proxy used by a program you don't have the source for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your console application's use one of the built-in methods for downloading web pages (WebClient, HttpWebRequest, etc.), they all have a [Proxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) which should do what you're after. They pretty much all work the same so here's the example provided by the MSDN documentation for HttpWebRequest.Proxy:

```
// Create a new request to the mentioned URL.               
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");

// Obtain the 'Proxy' of the  Default browser.  
IWebProxy proxy = myWebRequest.Proxy;
// Print the Proxy Url to the console.
if (proxy != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proxy: {0}", proxy.GetProxy(myWebRequest.RequestUri));
} 
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proxy is null; no proxy will be used");
}

WebProxy myProxy=new WebProxy();

Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the new Proxy Address that is to be set:");
Console.WriteLine("(Example:http://myproxy.example.com:port)");
string proxyAddress;

try
{
    proxyAddress =Console.ReadLine();
    if(proxyAddress.Length>0)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the Credentials (may not be needed)");
    Console.WriteLine("Username:");
    string username;
    username =Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("\nPassword:");
    string password;
    password =Console.ReadLine();                   
    // Create a new Uri object.
    Uri newUri=new Uri(proxyAddress);
    // Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
    myProxy.Address=newUri;
    // Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
    // Proxy property of request object.
    myProxy.Credentials=new NetworkCredential(username,password);
    myWebRequest.Proxy=myProxy;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe Address of the  new Proxy settings are {0}",myProxy.Address);
    HttpWebResponse myWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own proxy authentication class for each console application.

```
namespace YourProxyNameSpace
{
  public class YourProxyClass: IWebProxy
  {
        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            string proxy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxyaddress"];
            return new Uri(proxy);
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get
            {
                string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
                return new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            }
            set { }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the below node in the configuration file (app.config)

```
<system.net>    
<defaultProxy>
<module type="YourProxyNameSpace.YourProxyClass, YourProxyNameSpace"/>    
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>


 <add key="proxyaddress" value="http://proxyAddress:PORT"/>
    <add key="username" value="*****"/>
    <add key="password" value="*****"/>
```

Hope it helps someone. :)